# How to make PostreSQL functions private (inaccessible to end users)?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-10, sql-injection

When writing a set of PostgreSQL functions with procedural languages, is it possible to make *some* of the supporting functions private and not accessible by end users?

I wanted to refactor some common patterns into SQL functions, but are concerned about introducing potential SQL injection in the function parameters. For example, I wanted to implement a `copy_table(src regclass, target text)` function for copying a table to new table (in [a previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200419)), the second parameter can be subject to SQL-injection if unquoted. (Quoting the 2nd parameter has its own issues as discussed there). On the one hand, I wanted to write this function as a helper function for other public-facing functions; on the other, I don't want to expose it to everyone for security concerns.

Is there a way to hide the dangerous supporting functions so that they can only be called by my functions?

Comment: I think you need to state why you think private/public would have anything to do with SQL-injection. SQL-Injection is called by a failure to escape parameters. I don't believe it has anything to do with the question.

Comment: Also, when you say "supporting functions" what do you mean?

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with SQL Injection. First, **every** function that gets **any** parameter unquoted is a target for SQL Injection. Second, it's not clear what the issues you were having that are not addressed in the answers there. Third your design is pretty flawed, which is [*exactly* what I answered with a few days ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200427/2639) If your public facing functions are dropping and recreating tables in unspecified schemas, you have a large footprint for attack.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`REVOKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html) to control the permissions Postgres assigns to roles.

Documentation:

> The `REVOKE` command revokes previously granted privileges from one or more roles. The key word `PUBLIC` refers to the implicitly defined group of all roles.
>
> See the description of the [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) command for the meaning of the privilege types.

```
CREATE FUNCTION nocando()
RETURNS void AS $$
  SELECT null::void
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

REVOKE ALL
  ON FUNCTION nocando ()
  FROM PUBLIC ;
```